# Difference between one pass (scan) and two pass(scan)

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I had an Interview, a day before.
The Interviewer told me to , " Write a program to add a node at the end of a linked list ".
I had given him a solution. but he told me to implement it in one pass (one scan).
Can Anybody explain me, whats the meaning of one pass, and how to find the program written is in one pass or two pass?

  Here is my code

```
public void atLast(int new_data)                             
{
    Node new_node=new Node(new_data);               
    if(head==null)                                  
    {
        head=new Node(new_data);
        return;
    }
    new_node.next=null;                              
    Node last=head;                                 
    while(last.next!=null)
    {
        last=last.next;
    }
    last.next=new_node;                             
    return;
}
```

Comment: What *was* your solution? A "pass" refers to a single iteration through a collection. So "one pass" means to iterate through the nodes only once; two passes being twice, etc.

Comment: Perhaps tell us your solution to see if it really wasn't in one pass

Comment: That looks like a single pass to me.

Comment: I wonder that the interviewer might be wanted to confuse me. thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the code you gave the interviewer must have misread it because it is a single pass.

In your case a "pass" would be your `while` loop. It could also be done with recursion, `for`, or any other type of loop that goes through the elements in the array (or other form of a list of items).

In your code you run through the list of `Node` and insert the element at the end. This is done in one loop making it a single pass.

Now to look at a case with two passes. Say for example you were asked to remove the element with the largest value and wrote something similar to this:

```
int index = 0;
int count = 0;
int max = 0;
while(temp_node != null)
{
    if(temp_node.data > max)
    {
        index = count;
        max = temp_node.data;
    }
    count++;
    temp_node = temp_node.next;
}

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if(i == index)
    {
        //Functionality to remove node.
    }
}
```

The first pass (`while`) detects the `Node` which has the maximum value. The second pass (`for`) removes this `Node` by looping through all the elements again until the correct one is found.

Comment: its an easy explanation, thanks , now its clear to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine "two passes" here means that you iterated through the whole list twice in your code. You shouldn't need to do that to add a new node.